# Orthogonal Projection of $y$ onto $\operatorname{Col}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times m$ matrix with linearly independent columns. Let $y$ be a vector
in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $\operatorname{Proj}_{\operatorname{Col}(A)}y=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$.

I think I am supposed to prove that $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$ is the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto $\operatorname{Col}(A)$.

I am not sure how to go about this though.

Comment: Is $\mathrm{Col}(A)$ the column space of $A$?

Comment: What have you tried, and what do you already know? For instance, do you have a definition of the orthogonal projection?

Comment: What geometrically characterizes the projection of a vector $y$ into a subspace $V$? Your answer should have two parts.

Comment: @mc17 Have you already discussed the least-squares solution to a linear system of equations?

Answer (score 1):

Let $V:= \mathrm{Col}(A)$. I assume that the $\mathrm{Proj}_V y$ is defined as the unique vector such that
$$
(y - \mathrm{Proj}_V y)^\top v = 0
$$
for all $v \in V$. Since $V$ is the column space, we can rewrite this as finding $z \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that
$$
(y - Az)^\top Ax = 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^m.
$$
Let us manipulate this equation:
$$
y^\top Ax - z^\top A^\top A x = 0 \iff (y^\top A - z^\top A^\top A)x = 0
$$
So solving $y^\top A - z^\top A^\top A = 0$ would suffice. This yields $z = (A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top y$. Plugging this in, leaves
$$
\mathrm{Proj}_V y = A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top y.
$$

What is left to prove is that $A^\top A$ is in fact invertible: Since the columns of $A$ are l.i., we have $\mathrm{rank}(A) = m$. Now note that trivially $\mathrm{ker}(A) \subseteq \mathrm{ker} (A^\top A)$. Furthermore if $x \in \mathrm{ker}(A^\top A)$, we have
$$
0 = x^\top A^\top Ax = \lVert Ax \rVert_2^2.
$$
But by norm properties, we get $Ax = 0$, so $x \in \mathrm{ker}(A)$. So $\mathrm{ker}(A) = \mathrm{ker} (A^\top A)$. By the rank nullity-theorem, we have:
$$
m = \dim\mathrm{ker}(A) + \mathrm{rank}(A) = \dim \mathrm{ker}(A^\top A) + m \iff \dim\mathrm{ker}(A^\top A) = 0
$$
But this means that $A^\top A$ is invertible.

There is an alternative to the first part of the proof. The projection onto $V$ could also be defined as $Ax^*$ where $x^*$ is the minimizer of $g:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$
g(x) := \frac{1}{2} \lVert y - Ax \rVert^2_2.
$$
One could do some calculus and find a solution to
$$
A^\top Ax - A^\top y = \nabla g(x) \overset{!}{=} 0.
$$
This is our vector $z$. Regularity of $A$ then gives positive definiteness of thw hessian $A^\top A = D^2 g(x)$ on the entire domain, i.e. that $z$ is a unique minimizer.